# Procedure for computing operator norms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Endow $\mathbb R^m$ with the $p$-norm, and $\mathbb R^n$ with the $q$-norm. Is there an algorithm to compute the operator norm on the space of linear transformations $T : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$, given $p$ and $q$?

Comment: I only know how to do this when $p = q = 2$, where it becomes a computation of the first singular value $\sigma_1$ of $T$. There are various algorithms for doing this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I already know the cases $p = q = 1$, $p = q = 2$ and $p = q = \infty$, and I can probably work out by myself the other cases where $p, q \in {1, 2, \infty}$. Still, I wanted to know if there was a general procedure that works for any values of $p$ and $q$.